# HTTP 500 as response to an HTTP Post request using a Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, internal-server-error

I want to response my `Json` Object after my Post request but when i do this i've got an internal server `HTTP 500`.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.example.demo.beans.*;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import programm.Manager;

@Controller

public class StudentRegistrationController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public StudentRegistrationReply registerStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        JsonObject t;
        StudentRegistrationReply stdregreply = new StudentRegistrationReply();
        StudentRegistration.getInstance().add(student);
        //Manager m = new Manager();
        t = Manager.solvingProcess(student.getContext(), student.getFilename());
        stdregreply.setSolution(t);
        return stdregreply;
    }

}
```

Call the Method at Manager is no problem it do everything what it should. But at Postman e.g., I got a HTTP 500 and I don't understand why.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-10T06:28:21.159+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/"
}
```

Has anyone an idea? My Manager class only format an String into `JSONObject` with `JSONArray` inside, there works everything fine.

Comment: Log the t and the time it took solvingProcess to work.

Comment: _{"ComputingNode":[{"id":"CN 1","AppInstance":[{"id":"AI 1","name":"App 3"},{"id":"AI 5","name":"App 2"},{"id":"AI 6","name":"App 2"}]},{"id":"CN 2","AppInstance":[{"id":"AI 2","name":"App 2"},{"id":"AI 3","name":"App 1"},{"id":"AI 4","name":"App 1"}]},{"id":"CN 3","AppInstance":[]},{"id":"CN 4","AppInstance":[]}]}_

when i log t i've got the expected result.

Duration about 6.1 Seconds cause i connect to a DB via hibernate.

Comment: I think someone else has to come up with an answer. Timeout? You could try to fake the answer.

Comment: I think it isn't a Timeout because i added the following line ```t.addProperty("test", "1");``` and comment out the method call.

Comment: add error logs description, logs are useful to understand root cause any issue.

Comment: @BhushanUniyal how can i get the logs?

Comment: you can easily find logs in your IDE/Terminal console where you are executing this application, right?

Comment: Yeah right i only get there one Warning : ```2020-09-10 09:34:14.611  WARN 7615 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: JsonObject; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asDouble"])]
```
So i've testet if i get the right JSON output and how you can see at my second comment i've got the right JSON output in my class only the response doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem. The problem was i use JSON from google.gson and the httpresponse can't use it. I changed the JSON to Json from simple.json and everything works fine.